# Is it possible for ansible inventory to use variables according to group?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm new to ansible. I'm sorry if my question is basic.

Let's say I have a web server in a group called `web` in my inventory file. The same server is also in the `test` group. Something like this:

```yaml
web:
  hosts:
    vm01:
      ansible_host: foo.example.com
      ansible_user: user1
test:
  hosts:
    vm01:
      ansible_user: user2
```

If I run:

```bash
ansible-inventory -i inventory.yaml --list
```

I get the following output:

```json
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "vm01": {
                "ansible_host": "foo.example.com",
                "ansible_user": "user2"
            }
        }
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "test",
            "ungrouped",
            "web"
        ]
    },
    "test": {
        "hosts": [
            "vm01"
        ]
    },
    "web": {
        "hosts": [
            "vm01"
        ]
    }
}
```

First of all, why `vm01` is getting `ansible_user` variable from the `test` group?? Isn't it supposed to get it from the `web`??? According to [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#intro-inventory:%7E:text=By%20default%20Ansible%20merges%20groups%20at%20the%20same%20parent/child%20level%20in%20ASCII%20order:%7E:text=By%20default%20Ansible%20merges%20groups%20at%20the%20same%20parent/child%20level%20in%20ASCII%20order%2C), variables at the same level will have values according to the parent's ASCII order.

Second, is it possible to run ansible somehow, to use `ansible_user` variable from `test` group instead??

Comment: Do you mean [organizing host and group variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables)?

Comment: No, I just want to run ansible with ansible_user set to user 1 with the same inventory file. I don't know if it is possible or not. @U880D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Why `vm01` is getting `ansible_user` variable from the test group??*

According [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)

> *In general, Ansible gives precedence to variables that were defined more recently, more actively, and with more explicit scope.*

In other words, the last definition wins always.

> *Isn't it supposed to get it from the `web`???*

Therefore, no.

> *Is it possible to run ansible somehow, to use `ansible_user` variable from `test` group instead??*

Yes, by limiting the execution to that group (`test`) in example via [targeting hosts and groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html).